# Profit, Loss Dishonest seller

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A dishonest seller uses a weight of 800 gram in place of 1 kg and adds 20% impurities in sugar. What would be his profit percentage it he claims to be selling at the cost price?

**My approach**-

Let the cost price of 1 g sugar be £1

The person sells 1 kg sugar to customer at cost price which means the selling price would be £1 * 1000 = £1000

But in reality only 800 gram of sugar has been sold and that too has 20% impurity in it, which means the pure sugar out of this 800 gram would be 0.8 * 800 = 640 g , which would have costed him £640

Therefore the final profit would be £(1000-640) = £360, which is equivalent to (360/640) * 100%=56.25 %

The Answer given in the book is 50%, and also it gives a weird explanation for that which is SP=CP * (1000/800) * (1200/1000) => SP = 1.5 * CP => 50% profit

Please let me know in which step I am going wrong

Comment: If he dilutes his sugar with 20% fill, there is $\frac {1000}{1.2} = 833$ grams of sugar in a kilo (not 800).  Alternatively, if his mix is 800 g sugar and 200 g fill that is 25% filler.

Comment: Not able to understand your point, could you please elaborate it, which filler ? And how is it 1000/1.2=833 grams , if he has to sell 800 gram

Answer (score 1):

You have shown what would happen if the seller diluted his sugar with 25% impurities (hence the larger profit margin).

We dilute the sugar 20%.  1000 g of pure sugar becomes 1200 g of debased sugar.

Or 1000g of debased sugar has $\frac {1000}{1.2} = 833.3 $g of pure sugar and $166.3$ g of additives.

We can check $\frac {166.6}{833.3} = 0.2$

We then sell 800 grams of the stuff.   $\frac {800}{1.2} = 666.6g = \frac {2}{3} kg$ pure sugar.

The profit is $\frac {1}{3}$  £ the cost is $\frac 23$  £, the ratio $50\%$ margin.

Comment: but I took 20% impurities only , you can see I did 0.8 * 800 = 640

Comment: You took $640$ g of the original and added $160$ g of impurities.  That is 25% impurities to original.

Comment: it is the 800 grams which he is selling which has 20% impurities , then why are we not simply doing 80% only of 800

Comment: 20% of impurities was added to the original, which is less than saying 20% of the original was taken away and replaced with impurities.

Comment: what do you mean by original here ? the 800 grams ?

Comment: According to my understanding that instead of 1000 grams , he is actually selling 800 grams , and these 800 grams will contain the impurities part and the pure sugar , is this correct so far ?

Comment: He has one ton of sugar in his store.  He adds $200$ kg of filler to his supply and mixes it together.  He takes his scoop and takes $800$ g of this mixture to sell.  The $800$ g mixtures does not have $800\cdot 0.80$ g of his original sugar, it has $\frac {800}{1.2}$ g of the original sugar.

Comment: But isn't he adding the filler after weighing it ? I got carried away by this